# Mongoose sub-document deep populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to learn Mongdb with Nodejs and mongoose.
I cannot succeed to "deep populate" my mongoose query.

This is my Database:

```
companies: [{
    name:"test"
    users:[{
      name:"user1",
      role: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' } //5a32a0b0c592bb82f67602fa
    }]
  }],
roles:[{_id:"5a32a0b0c592bb82f67602fa",name:"ADMIN",label:"Administrator"}]
```

I would like to fetch the user "user1" and its role "ADMIN" of the company "test"
This is my query:

```
return this.companyModel.findOne({
        name: companyName,
        users: { $elemMatch: user }
    }).then((res: ICompany) => {
   if (!res) {
     throw new ResourceNotFound('User Not Found');
    }
   try {
     return res.users[0];
   }
   catch (e) { throw new ServerError('Server error'); }
 });
```

This is the output of the query:

```
{
  "_id": "5a32b2fed9d8579b906fb95d",
  "role": "5a32a0b0c592bb82f67602fa", <-- I need to populate this field
  "name": "user1"
}
```

Like this:

```
{
  "_id": "5a32b2fed9d8579b906fb95d",
  "role": {_id:"5a32a0b0c592bb82f67602fa",name:"ADMIN",label:"Administrator"},
  "name": "user1"
}
```

How Can I populate the field "role"?
I tried several time with "populate" but I didn't succeed!

**EDIT**

I found the following solution:

```
return this.companyModel.findOne({
        name: companyName,
        users: { $elemMatch: user }
    }).then((res: ICompany) => {
   if (!res) {
     throw new ResourceNotFound('User Not Found');
    }
   try {
     return this.roleModel.populate(res.users[0], { "path": "role" }).then(fullUser => {
                return fullUser;
     })
   }
   catch (e) { throw new ServerError('Server error'); }
 });
```

Is this the better way to achieve what I need or there is a most elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). That could help you with this.

Comment: I've simplified a bit my database, Now I have 2 separated collections "roles" and "companies" (I've updated the main post).
I tried to use the lookup but I didn't figure out how to do that.
Can you please give me a little hint?
Thank you